# Inserted DOM Content Not Displaying In Chrome Without Resize

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, dom

This one has me stumped. I have three columns using divs with table layouts, all with 100% height. When I dynamically insert content that contains wrapping divs with `position: relative` and then `position: absolute` into one of the columns, Chrome won't show the new content unless the browser window is resized. It appears as though the outer wrapper is set to 0 height until the resize. IE and Firefox work as expected (the content shows immediately).

Update: I'll also add it appears related to the `overflow: hidden` style set on `scroll-wrapper` - if that is removed it works fine in Chrome too.

Here's a running example on CodePen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/raqJEz

Full code embedded here as well (though it appears you need to use the "Full Page" option when running on StackOverflow to actually see the behavior - it replicates in CodePen at any size):

```js
$(document).on("click", ".col1-link", function () {
  $("#col2").html('<div class="relative-wrapper"> \
        <div class="scroll-wrapper"> \
          Col2 \
        </div> \
      </div>');
});
```

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.table-div {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}
.table-row {
  display: table-row;
  width: 100%;
}
.table-cell {
  display: table-cell;
  float: none;
  padding: 0;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.full-height {
  height: 100%;
}
.relative-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
}
.scroll-wrapper {
  overflow: hidden !important;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}

#col1 {
  width: 15%;
}

#col2 {
  width: 25%;
  padding: 0;
}

#col3 {
  width: 60%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="table-div full-height">
  <div class="table-row full-height">
    <div id="col1" class="table-cell full-height">
      <a class="col1-link" href="#">Click Here</a>
    </div>
    <div id="col2" class="table-cell full-height">
    </div>
    <div id="col3" class="table-cell full-height">
      After click, "Col2" will only be visible after resizing the window on Chrome, but works fine in IE and Firefox
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Any ideas why this might be happening?

Comment: It looks like chrome doesn't bother to recalculate the height until it thinks it has to. You could hack it a bit and say `$('#col2').html(...).height(0);`, which will make the browser recalculate the height.

Comment: @Chad - you look to be on to something here. The funny thing is that once it calculates the height once, it never needs to do it again, even after subsequent resizes or additional DOM insertions. It's like Chrome needs a good kick-in-the-pants to tell it that particular element might change size.

Comment: I think it's just a table display bug of some sort. If you look at this with `display: inline-block` instead of `display: table-cell`, it calculates fine: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dPgmJB

Comment: @Chad I think you've got the gist of it. If you write up your comments as an answer, I'll go ahead and accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of different solutions. For some reason it has to do with the table display and how chrome calculates the height of table cells (or doesn't). You can either switch off of the table display, which I'm assuming you don't want to do, or you can trigger the height recalculation with a javascript function.

```js
$(document).on("click", ".col1-link", function () {
  $("#col2").html('<div class="relative-wrapper"> \
        <div class="scroll-wrapper"> \
          Col2 \
        </div> \
      </div>').height(0);
});
```

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.table-div {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}
.table-row {
  display: table-row;
  width: 100%;
}
.table-cell {
  display: table-cell;
  float: none;
  padding: 0;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.full-height {
  height: 100%;
}
.relative-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
}
.scroll-wrapper {
  overflow: hidden !important;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}

#col1 {
  width: 15%;
}

#col2 {
  width: 25%;
  padding: 0;
}

#col3 {
  width: 60%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="table-div full-height">
  <div class="table-row full-height">
    <div id="col1" class="table-cell full-height">
      <a class="col1-link" href="#">Click Here</a>
    </div>
    <div id="col2" class="table-cell full-height">
    </div>
    <div id="col3" class="table-cell full-height">
      After click, "Col2" will only be visible after resizing the window on Chrome, but works fine in IE and Firefox
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Now, because it's a table display, setting a height of 0 should not actually affect the element's height, but will cause chrome to recalculate the height correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You can fix the height issue by either setting 'overflow:auto' to your 'relative-wrapper' css class or change the absolute positioned 'scroll-wrapper' to relative.

I'm not sure tho if this is the best solution out there.

Comment: He already has that solution, just looking for an answer to why it happens.

Comment: @Chad - I actually hadn't tried adding `overflow: auto;` to the outer `relative-wrapper` class yet, and it does resolve this problem (though introduces some other problems in my real-world case). While you are right that I am primarily looking for "why" this is happening, I appreciate the suggestion. I certainly don't think it merits a downvote.

Comment: @somedave I thought it was in your post that you had tried that and it fixed it in chrome

Comment: @Chad I had tried removing the `overflow: hidden` on `scroll-wrapper`, I hadn't thought to change the `overflow` of `relative-wrapper`. I'll edit the question to make that clearer.